# Excluding namespaces that are only used for forward declaration in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using Doxygen v1.9.0. I have the following classes in my project:

```cpp
// x.h
namespace A {
    class X {
        ...
    };
}
```

```cpp
// y.h
namespace A {
    class X;
}

namespace B {
    class Y {
        Y(A::X*);
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to only export `y.h` via doxygen with namespaces enabled. However, when I do this, I also get a generated page for `namespace A` with nothing inside of it.

I found [this question](https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/32202449/) from 2014, but I was wondering if there was anything in newer versions of doxygen that would be able to ignore empty namespaces if they are just filled with forward declarations/are empty.

Comment: doxygen 1.9.0 is from December 27, 2020, the current doxygen version is 1.9.7 can you try that one? Furthermore what is in your doxygen settings file different from the default settings (i.e. the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile)?